# Why is the => symbol appearing in my code?

Tags: ruby

I just started learning how to code and I tried running some basic instructions.
To start, I have the following:

```
print 'hello'
v= "yes"
["test","words","okay"].
each do |v|
puts  "This is the test word #{v}"
end
```

which gives me the following out put

```
irb(main):053:0> print 'hello'
hello=> nil
irb(main):054:0> v= "yes"
=> "yes"
irb(main):055:0> ["test","words","okay"].
irb(main):056:0* each do |v|
irb(main):057:1* puts  "This is the test word #{v}"
irb(main):058:1> end
This is the test word test
This is the test word words
This is the test word okay
=> ["test", "words", "okay"]
```

Why exactly is the => symbol appearing at the end of my code which references back to my array of strings? From what I understand so far, I know that => can be used to assign Strings to symbols in hashes (I think), but what other purpose does the symbol serve and why is it in my code?

Comment: `=>` indicates the beginning of the return value. It has nothing to do with the notation used in hashes.

Comment: Your examples make it hard to understand its meaning. Try to enter `1 + 2` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `=>` you are seeing is an indicator of the return value of whatever command you run using irb.

So for instance the command `print 'hello'` results in `hello=> nil` because the string 'hello' is output to the console (with no new line), and the return value of the print method is nil.

When you invoke the `each` method on an array, after your output text is printed you see `=> ["test", "words", "okay"]` because that is the return value of the `each` method (this can be convenient because it allows for chaining methods together).

As an experiment, try running different commands to see what their return values are. What is the return value of an assignment? (E.G. `a = 3`). Can you think of any useful ways to use return values?

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you very much for the answer! I'm excited to start learning Ruby and it's definitely an interesting experience. Would you happen to have any suggestions as to how I should pick up the language other than just writing (somewhat) random pieces of code?

Comment: Pick a small project around something that interests you (print out a multiplication table, play tic tac toe, look up tomorrows weather), implement it with ruby, polish it, repeat.